# python convert dataframe to json with \n

Tags: python, json, dataframe

We converted dataframe to json using `to_json()`, but `\n` disappears in the string. How can I convert while keeping `\n`?
Before conversion, dataframe has \n, which disappears when converted

now:

```
companyId:"ckurudq3r00efkakh4hgu33pn"
tagName:
contact:"0336443303"
phone:"01066449675"
virtualNumber:"050413736583"
partner:false
certificate:false
memo:null
businesshours:"Mon~Fri: 09:00AM ~ 06:00PM Sat: 09:00AM ~ 06:00PM Sun: 09:00AM ~ 06:00PM"
```

what i want:

```
companyId:"ckurudq3r00efkakh4hgu33pn"
tagName:
contact:"0336443303"
phone:"01066449675"
virtualNumber:"050413736583"
partner:false
certificate:false
memo:null
businesshours:"Mon~Fri: 09:00AM ~ 06:00PM\nSat: 09:00AM ~ 06:00PM\nSun: 09:00AM ~ 06:00PM"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running through something similar to this and I do not remember that I could figure it out so I came up with a workaround.

```
#replace '\n' with '\\n'
df.replace('\n', '\\n', inplace= True)
# export normally
df.to_json('path')
```

whenever you want to open it back, just read the file and again replace any '\\n' with '\n'